# How to get a few words from a text with a specific word in this excerpt?

Tags: php

(Let's have a good start : I'm sorry for my bad english.)

*I'm using Php5+.*

Here's the thing : I'm trying to get a 5 or 6 words long excerpt (extract ?) from a long text, around a specific word.

With this text :

```
Hello my name is Bryan, I am in the kitchen but I do love umbrellas and cats. I'm not a dog person.
```

If I'm targeting the word "kitchen", I'd like to obtain :

```
"[...] in the kitchen but I do [...]"
```

I guess I have to use regex and stuff, but to be honest I have no idea how to do it.

And in an harder way, I'd like to get as many excerpt as the word is encountered in the text.

Thx for your advices.

Comment: Are you looking for this https://regex101.com/r/uCMgXC/1 ?

Comment: How complex do you want your system to be? From what I can see, your best option might be to get all the stop words ( things like dots, commas, 'but', 'then', 'after' etc), then break your string into multiple sections using `explode()` command and find which elements contain word of interest.

Comment: You could explode on spaces, find your term, then join the nearest X indices on the left and right.

Comment: You could easily do this without regex, which I would suggest if you don't understand the regex you would be using. Here is a recipe: [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string on whitespace, find the element "kitchen" and remember its index, then pick the two elements before and the three element after that and glue them back together. Of course, always check if you're out of bounds and always remember that you might not actually find the element "kitchen" at all.

Comment: Two ways to do it, and to very good ways !
Thx a lot guys, I'll take a look at that ! It was so simple to guess, it's almost a shame I didn't think of it sooner.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something like that:

```
<?php
$subject = "Hello my name is Bryan, I am in the kitchen but I do love umbrellas and cats. I'm not a dog person.";
$pattern = '/\w+\s+\w+\s+kitchen\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);
var_dump('[...] ' . $tokens[0] . ' [...]');
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(35) "[...] in the kitchen but I do [...]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx to your advices guys, I found a solution.

I used Regex, because `split/explode` is limited (you can split with just one character and sometimes you want this character, so even `preg_split` is not good)

As I want to find the specific word even if it is in the beginning/end of a line, between other words or in the beginning/end of a sentence etc, I made this regex :

```
((?:[\p{L}.,?!;:]+ +){1,3}|\b)(kitchen)((?:[ ',]+[\p{L}.,?!;:']+){1,3}|\b)
```

If you have a better one, tell me. If you have question about it, ask me !

(See it https://regex101.com/r/e69l2m/1 )